# In TYPO3 Fluid, how to pass additional arguments to a partial when {_all} is used

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

Fluid Styled Content uses the `f:render` Viewhelper as such:

```
<f:render partial="Header" arguments="{_all}" />
```

I'd like to pass another info to the partial, like

```
<f:render partial="Header" arguments="{_all, settings : doThis}" />
```

But it seems to me that's the wrong way, as it throws an error.

I also tried accessing `settings.doThis` with `f:alias`, but no luck (or rather, skill) either.

How's that done correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible with the alias ViewHelper. I already used it with TYPO3 version 6 and 7.

Just extend the {_all} var as following

## Partial

```
<f:alias map="{additionalVar: 'foobar'}">
        <f:render partial="Partial" arguments="{_all}"/>
</f:alias>
```

## Section

```
<f:alias map="{additionalVar: 'foobar'}">
    <f:render section="Section" arguments="{_all}" />
</f:alias>
```

You can use the "additionalVar" variable as any other.

It is working with section and partial.

Comment: `<f:variable name="foo" value="bar" />` can also be used...

Answer (score 2):

You can't, so just modify your `settings` (or any other var) in the controller yet or use ViewHelper, which allows you to declare vars in the view, like i.e.: [v:variable.set](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Variable/SetViewHelper.html) of VHS ext.

Comment: Which solution did you choose, just for curiosity? Personally I still have doubts, usually prefer _controller approach_

Comment: As I did it before your solution arrived, I simply switched the entire Partial. When I refactor it, I'll go for `v:variable.set` – it's normal templating, not an extension, so I don't have a controller (as far as I know)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use this one, but don´t use the var 'settings'. This one is used by typoscript.

```
<f:render partial="Header" arguments="{_all, myvar:'myvalue'}" />
```

Try the `<f:debug>` tag in the Header Partial and see

Comment: Not working for me in TYPO3 8: : The argument "arguments" was registered with type "array", but is of type "string" in view helper "TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\ViewHelpers\RenderViewHelper

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vhs viewhelper` with fluid like below.

```
<v:variable.set value="{yourValue}" name="variable">
<f:render partial="Header" arguments="{_all, newVar:variable}" />
```